# How to configure Spring ConversionService with java config?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

I have such xml:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <list>
                <bean class="converters.AddressToStringConverter" />
                <bean class="converters.StringToAddressConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

It configures converters without problems.

But then this code fails to make the same:

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        bean.setConverters(getConverters());
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        ConversionService object = bean.getObject();
        return object;
    }

    private Set<Converter> getConverters() {
        Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<Converter>();

        converters.add(new AddressToStringConverter());
        converters.add(new StringToAddressConverter());

        return converters;
    }
}
```

This piece of configuration gets scanned by context - I checked it with debugger. Where could be the problem?

Comment: NB: you do not need to do the `afterPropertiesSet()` and `return bean.getObject()` - just return the factory bean, Spring will invoke `afterPropertiesSet()` and `getObject()` for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my point of view your problem is the `Bean` name. Once you don't explicit set the name using `@Bean(name="conversionService")` the name that will be used is `getConversionService`.

From [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#name%28%29):

> The name of this bean, or if plural, aliases for this bean. If left
>   unspecified the name of the bean is the name of the annotated method.
>   If specified, the method name is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

In SpringMVC you can extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and use it for Java based config. To register custom converters you can modify the "addFormatters"-Method like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "..." })
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry)
    {
        formatterRegistry.addConverter(getMyConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public StringToCounterConverter getMyConverter()
    {
        return new StringToCounterConverter();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enable logging, you'll see which Beans are created by Spring, as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-bean-annotation).

*Log configuration*

```
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="DEBUG" />
```

*Log output*

```
    DEBUG (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) - Finished creating instance of bean 'getConversionService'
```

I copy+pasted your code and it worked without changing the name. I injected the `ConversionService` as follows:

```
@Resource
private ConversionService conversionService;
```

This works because of [Autowiring by type](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire). So maybe you had two `ConversionService` beans.