# WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and annotation-driven conflict?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I am trying to implement converter in SpringMVC and configure it like in
[How to configure Spring ConversionService with java config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273443/how-to-configure-spring-conversionservice-with-java-config)
and some weird things happened.

ApplicationConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
        formatterRegistry.addConverter(new StringToFoo());
        formatterRegistry.addConverter(new FooToString());
    }
}
```

I have a jsp with a form to pass a Foo object to controller. 
And I have `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and component-scan in xml.

It turns out that the code I quoted was executed at init, but the converters were not called when passing from jsp to controller,

When I delete annotation-driven, everything works, converter was correctly called in my controller. However, before I added WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to the proejct, I had to include annotation-driven to init servlet.

So my questions:

What does annotation-driven do?
Does WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (or the annotations used) have conflict with annotation-driven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EnableWebMvc is doing the same as annotation-driven, it is just in java instead of xml. When you have both it seems it gives the annotation-driven precedence and therefore the converters are not registered.  Also see this question [EnableWebMvc annotation meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291329/enablewebmvc-annotation-meaning)